# Eclipse Plugin development: How to get the targetID for a viewerContribution

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to contribute a popup menu action to an existing editor which is provided by a 3rd party plugin. Inside my viewerContribution I need to specify targetID of the editor I want to add the menu entry to - but how do I get to that ID?

The sample code I found so far only contributes to self made editors but never to something that's already there.

This is pre Eclipse 3.5 so I use the "old" org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus extension point.

Answer (score 5):

See Plug-in Spy.

Hit Alt + Shift + F1 on an editor to see its ID and contributers.

Plug-in Menu Spy
Press Alt + Shift + F2 will change the mouse cursor to spy mode. Now select an menu entry. It will reveal the menu ID and its contributers.

btw...you can not get ID for some platform contributed menu items because they don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the interface summary and class summary of all the Eclipse IDE contents [here.](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fviews%2Ftasklist%2Fpackage-summary.html)